# How to output file sizes in human-readable format in an rsync logfile

Tags: linux, formatting, rsync, logfiles

I know that the `-h` option outputs file sizes in human-readable format when, for example, displaying the transfer progress with `--progress`.

But is it possible to get this same file size formatting in the log files? I see options/escapes to display the number of bytes being transferred (`%b`) and also the total size of the file (`%l`), but don't see any way to output more human-readable equivalents for these values.

Answer (score 2):

Found this [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/rsync/rsyncd.conf.html) `rsyncd.conf -- configuration file for rsync in daemon mode` ...

```
  
log format  
    This parameter allows you to specify the format used for logging file  
    transfers when transfer logging is enabled. The format is a text string   
    containing embedded single-character escape sequences prefixed with a  
    percent (%) character. An optional numeric field width may also be   
    specified between the percent and the escape letter (e.g. "%-50n %8l %07p").   

    In addition, one or more apostrophes may be specified prior to a   
    numerical escape to indicate that the numerical value should be made   
    more human-readable. The 3 supported levels are the same as for the  
    --human-readable command-line option, though the default is for human-  
    readability to be off. Each added apostrophe increases the level  
    (e.g. "%''l %'b %f").
```